# Can't change the page number of an API URL I'm fetching

Tags: javascript, url, fetch-api

I'm trying to change the page number of an API's endpoint using a variable instead of the actual number. It's a list of products, in each page it displays 8 items. I was able to render it in the HTML, but I also need to make an expansive product list (which I'm having trouble with as well).

But I cant make it work. The number is changing in the `console.log`, but not on the URL I'm fetching. Weirdly, it does use the variable number I placed.

Here is the full JS code:

```js
let page = 1

const btnPage = document.querySelector('#nextPage')

btnPage.addEventListener('click', () => {
    page++
    console.log(page)
})

function fetchData() {
    fetch(`https://frontend-intern-challenge-api.iurykrieger.vercel.app/products?page=${page}`)
        .then(response => {
            if(!response.ok) {
                throw Error('ERROR');
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data.products);

            const html = data.products
                .map(product => {
                    return `
                    <div class="products-item">
                        <img src="https:${product.image}" alt="Imagem" class="products-item-img"/>
                        <div class="products-item--info">    
                            <h4>${product.name}</h4>
                            <p id="product-description">${product.description}</p>
                            <p>De: R$${product.oldPrice}</p>
                            <h3>Por: R$${product.price}</h3>
                            <p>ou 2x de R$${parseFloat((product.price) / 2)}</p>
                            <button>Comprar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;

                    //HTML generated inside the div class "products-wraper"
                })
                .join("");

            document.getElementById('products').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
            //.insertAdjacentHTML ratter than .innerHTML to avoid corrupting references
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}

fetchData()
```

And the HTML linked that is been rendered:

```html
<main>
     <div class="products">
        <div class="products-wraper" id="products"></div>
        <button class="products-plus" id="nextPage">Ainda mais produtos aqui!</button>
     </div>
</main>
```

I'm using that button to try and change the page number.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code that has been posted, I don't see how `fetchData()` is called, aside from on page load.. On page load, `page` will always be `1`, as a user hasn't had a chance to hit the button yet..

Should `fetchData()` be called within the event listener callback for clicking on the button?